Limit of a complex function: Check all cases

When we say, "Find whether the limit $$\lim_{z\to z_0}f(z)$$ exists or not (where $z_0$ is a complex number and $f(z)$ is a complex function)", we generally travel along these paths (consider $z_0=x_0+iy_0$)$:$

$1.$ $x\to x_0$ then $y\to y_0$
$2.$ $y\to y_0$ then $x\to x_0$
$3.$ $(y-y_0)=m(x-x_0)$ where $m\in\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$
And if the limit comes equal in these cases we say that the limit exists. This is what is expected from me in my college exams. But how does these cases ensure that the limit will exist for every path out there $?$ We can't check every path theoretically, so in a way we can't check whether the limit of any complex function at any point exists or not.
How to deal with this$?$ Any help is greatly appreciated.

These 3 types of paths are not sufficient. I think one way of proving continuity at a point $z$ would be to show that $f(z_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence and finding some subsequence $f(z_{n_k})$ for which showing $f(z_{n_k}) \rightarrow f(z)$ is easy (of course $z_n \rightarrow z$)

These paths or other specific paths can be used indeed to show that limit doesn't exist when we obtain different answer for different paths, otherwise this is not a way to prove existence.

If there was  a neat, simple  way of proving existence in general, the Mathematicians would lose their jobs. -:)

As has already been mentioned, the mentioned conditions are not enough for the limit to exist, and I will provide an example to show this.
Consider the function $f$ defined by
$$f(x+iy)=\begin{cases}
1,&y=x^2,\\
0,&\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$
The limit $\lim_{z\to0}f(z)$ then does not exist, as
$$\lim_{t\to0}f(t+it)=0,\quad \lim_{t\to0}f(t+it^2)=1.$$
We claim now that the limits you listed all exist and are equal to $0$. Observe first that for any fixed $y\in\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$ we have that $f(x+iy)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{y\}$, and in particularly it holds for all $x$ sufficiently close to $0$, and so
$$\lim_{x\to0}f(x+iy)=0,$$
for all $y\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, which implies that
$$\lim_{y\to0}\lim_{x\to0}f(x+iy)=0.$$
An identical argument shows that
$$\lim_{x\to0}\lim_{y\to0}f(x+iy)=0.$$
Finally, if $m\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ then $mt\neq t^2$ for all sufficiently small $t$ (as $\left\lvert\frac{mt}{t^2}\right\rvert\to\infty$ as $t\to0$), so $f(t+imt)=0$ for all sufficiently small $t$, and so
$$\lim_{t\to0}f(t+imt)=0.$$

Yes you are right that those three conditions are not sufficient to determine the limit at a point in general.
However for nice enough functions we can make estimates. Suppose for example that we have $f(z)=z^2$ and $z\to0$. Then if $|z|<\delta$, $|f(z)|<\delta^2$ which means that $f$ tends to $0$ as $z\to0$.
For an arbitrary function it is not an easy task to check limits.
